# Create and mount data-only containers with docker-compose

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

ocker 1.9 introduced a new volume API for creating data only containers (via `docker volume create`).
Is it possible to create those and mount them via docker-compose?

I would like to create a data only container to store data from my MySQL database (https://hub.docker.com/_/mysql/). Sadly I couldn't find any documentation whether it is possible with docker-compose itself.

**Is it possible as of Docker Compose 1.6.2. and if yes, how?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Considering that [compose/volume.py#L23](https://github.com/docker/compose/blob/7de9b08ca5d14c5d0a2eaeb78f0427a15180818b/compose/volume.py#L23) does include a `volume.create()` method, it should be possible.

See [the volume section of Compose file reference](https://github.com/docker/compose/blob/a6649b308e05a7a0bc65b607930e2aac5265c3fc/docs/compose-file.md#volumes-volume_driver):

```
volumes:
  # Just specify a path and let the Engine create a volume
  - /var/lib/mysql
 # Named volume
  - datavolume:/var/lib/mysql
```

That would call `docker volume create`.

Comment: As usual awesome  dig @VonC. Thank you for going where no man has gone before :P

Comment: @Hedge special thanks to the docker compose development team :)

Answer (score 0):

if you want to cretae and store database data make docker-compose.yml will look like
if you want to use Dockerfile

```
version: '3.1'

services:
  php:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    ports:
      - 80:80
    volumes:
      - ./src:/var/www/html/
  db:
    image: mysql
    command: --default-authentication-plugin=mysql_native_password
    restart: always
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: example
    volumes:
      - mysql-data:/var/lib/mysql

  adminer:
    image: adminer
    restart: always
    ports:
      - 8080:8080
volumes:
  mysql-data:
```

your docker-compose.yml will looks like
if you want to use your image instead of Dockerfile

```
version: '3.1'   

services:
  php:
    image: php:7.4-apache
    ports:
      - 80:80
    volumes:
      - ./src:/var/www/html/
  db:
    image: mysql
    command: --default-authentication-plugin=mysql_native_password
    restart: always
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: example
    volumes:
      - mysql-data:/var/lib/mysql

  adminer:
    image: adminer
    restart: always
    ports:
      - 8080:8080
volumes:
```

if you want to store or preserve data of mysql then
must remember to add two lines in your docker-compose.yml

```
volumes:
  - mysql-data:/var/lib/mysql
```

and

```
volumes:
  mysql-data:
```

after that use this command

```
docker-compose up -d
```

now your data will persistent and will not be deleted even after using this command

```
docker-compose down
```

extra:- but if you want to delete all data then you will use

```
docker-compose down -v
```